# Where is the "product problem" field in the openFDA API?

Tags: openfda, medical

In the [MAUDE search tool on FDA.gov](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfMAUDE/search.CFM) there is a standard list of problems in a product problem field. This is not available in the API. See screenshot for example.

This would be a great addition to the [OpenFDA API device/event endpoint](https://open.fda.gov/device/event/). Thoughts on if you can add?

[image: MAUDE screenshot]

Comment: Here's an example: compare http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfMAUDE/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=1693964 where there is a "Device Problem" of "Absorption" to the same record from the openFDA API: https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=BM2HCPM0

Answer (score 1):

This is a good feature request.  We are accepting these request via Github (https://github.com/FDA/openfda/issues) and we will keep you posted there.